# In elixir, how do I add functionality to a module coming from an external source (3rd party, stdlib, etc)?

Tags: elixir

I'm new to elixir and building a command line app to get familiar with mix and elixir without too many dependencies.

When I build command line apps, I tend to use ansi color codes to make output more readable.

`IO.ANSI` appears to only support 8 colors, which may be combined with things like `bright`, `underline`, etc. There is no way to get to the other 8 colors in a 16-color pallette.

The current source has the following code:

```
colors = [:black, :red, :green, :yellow, :blue, :magenta, :cyan, :white]

for {color, code} <- Enum.with_index(colors) do
  @doc "Sets foreground color to #{color}."
  defsequence color, code + 30

  @doc "Sets background color to #{color}."
  defsequence :"#{color}_background", code + 40
end
```

It seems that a trivial modification to achieve what I'm after would be to add the following lines to the existing function:

```
  @doc "Sets foreground color to light #{color}."
  defsequence :"light_#{color}", code + 90

  @doc "Sets background color to light #{color}."
  defsequence :"light_#{color}_background", code + 100
```

How do I achieve doing something like this (without forking code) in elixir? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify existing modules and this is by design. I wouldn't like anyone in my team to change something that I already know.

But it should be possible to create new module that does what you want.
`defsequence` is a macro that you can import from other module, so you could write:

```
defmodule IO.ExtendedANSI do
  import IO.ANSI.Sequence

  colors = [:black, :red, :green, :yellow, :blue, :magenta, :cyan, :white]

  for {color, code} <- Enum.with_index(colors) do
    @doc "Sets foreground color to light #{color}."
    defsequence :"light_#{color}", code + 90

    @doc "Sets background color to light #{color}."
    defsequence :"light_#{color}_background", code + 100
  end
end
```

But now, you would have to remember which function are from original `ANSI` and which one from `ExtendedANSI`. You could create a delegate for all functions existing in `ANSI`:

```
defmodule IO.ExtendedANSI do
  import IO.ANSI.Sequence

  IO.ANSI.__info__(:functions)
  |> Enum.each(fn {name, arity} ->
    args = Enum.map(:lists.seq(1, arity), fn(i) -> {:"arg#{i}", [], Elixir} end)
    defdelegate unquote({name, [], args}), to: IO.ANSI
  end)

  colors = [...]
    ...
end
```

Now you are able to call `IO.ExtendedANSI.blue()` and `IO.ExtendedANSI.light_blue()`.

The solution is not perfect though:

- We need to redefine `colors`, so if original one changes, we need to change our code too. I am not sure if there is a way to get it, because it is internal implementation detail
- Functions that take arguments like `def format(chardata, emit? \\ enabled?)` will properly display `See IO.ANSI.format/2` on help, but they will have signature `def fromat(arg1, arg2)`. There should be a way to do it somehow.

Comment: This is very much along the lines of what I was thinking would need to be done. However, while the functions are now included in the new module, I still get `(ArgumentError) invalid ANSI sequence specification: :light_red` when attempting to use one of them `IO.ExtendedANSI.format [:light_red, "foo"], true`. The standard colors work fine using the new module.

Comment: I see, `ExtendedANSI` delegates to `ANSI`, which internally uses only `ANSI` and doesn't know about new colors.
There might be another way to achieve exactly what you need, but it is more involved. You could use this technique http://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-get-the-ast-of-an-elixir-program/ to get entire AST of `ANSI` module, modify its internals (the `color` variable) and save it as another module.